# Why have SVG transitions become slower in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, d3.js, svg, transition

[This animated SVG map](http://metrocosm.com/build-cartogram.html) was made with D3js. It transitions between a normal world map and a deformed cartogram, as shown in the image.
[image: animated cartogram]

Below is the code I'm using for the transitions. polygon and polygon2 are geojson objects pre-projected to screen coordinates.

```
var path = d3.geo.path().projection(null);
function map1(){
    worldmap.data(polygon.features).transition().duration(2000).attr("d", path);    
}
function map2(){
    worldmap.data(polygon2.features).transition().duration(2000).attr("d", path);       
}
```

When the map was made in 2015, the SVG transition was clean and smooth in Chrome (and still is in Firefox). But when it's run in Chrome today (Version 65.0.3325.181), the transition is slow and choppy.

Please help. What changed in Chrome to make transitions so slow?

Comment: The question as it is now is borderline opinion-based and lacks code. Can you clarify? What versions of Chrome are affected? How are the transitions created? Is this just your personal perception or do you have quantifiable proof for this? Can you set up a [mcve] with the emphasis on *minimal*.?

Comment: As a hint for tracking this down: d3 uses the [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) API for animations.

Comment: @altocumulus Until recently, the map transition (linked) ran in Chrome as smoothly as it currently does in Firefox. Today, the difference is night and day. I do not know of a way to replicate the smooth transition in Chrome. That is precisely the problem.

Comment: @mgalka Interestingly enough, it runs smoothly on my MacBook using Chrome v65.0.3325.181, whereas it stutters on my Windows computer using the very same version of Chrome...

Comment: @mgalka This isn't relevant directly, but how (with what script/software) did you preproject the cartogram? I'm trying to do something very similar but d3.cartogram doesn't work with d3.js v4.

Comment: @markus I did it in d3. Just create a projection function and pass it the array of coordinates. That map comes from a post I wrote a post about making cartograms: http://metrocosm.com/how-to-make-cartograms-with-animation/